# Data entity definition language

Tags: data, modeling, language

I'm aware that most languages allow you to define data entities and the relationships between then in various ways; but I'm wondering if there's anything that's targeted specifically at holding this definition; which can then be used by other tools.

Specifically, we have entities which crop up multiple times in different systems; and each time we have to recreate that entity's definition in the appropriate language (unless there's a data source we can connect to to generate that definition from).

It would be great to define our entities / data model in some language agnostic way, and store these in a git repo; then use some tool to generate (and update) the appropriate classes/tables/structs for these entities in the language of our choice in our various projects' repositories.

Is anyone aware of anything like this?